# How to call an event handler when the value in a text box in an ASP.Net Razor Pages app is changed?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm building a web application using ASP.NET CORE 3.1. There is a data table(EvCode) that has two columns, EventCode (key field) and EventType.  On the page that lets a user add a new event there are a number of fields.  Among them is EventCode and EventType.  When the EventCode is entered and the user exits the field, I want to trigger an event that queries the EvCode table using the the value in the EventCode field to select the EventType, then populate the the EventType field with the value.

If I add a button to the page, I can run the event handler.  I need the event handler to run automatically when the value in the EventCode field is changed.

Any suggestions or ideas  on how to do this are appreciated.

Fei Han  -  Thank you for your suggestions and code.  I used a different project where I trying to accomplish the same thing.  The only differences, rather than using EventCode I used FamilyCode, and rather than use EventType I used FamilyName.  The handler (OnGetFamilyNameByCode) was never called.

I've included my code, maybe you can see what I've done wrong.`

```
<form method="get" >
    <div class="border backgroundWhite">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-2">
                <label asp-for="PublisherFamilyVM.PubDataList.LastName"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <input asp-for="PublisherFamilyVM.PubDataList.LastName" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <span asp-validation-for="PublisherFamilyVM.PubDataList.LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-2">
                <label asp-for="PublisherFamilyVM.PubDataList.FirstName"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <input asp-for="PublisherFamilyVM.PubDataList.FirstName" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <span asp-validation-for="PublisherFamilyVM.PubDataList.FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-2">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PublisherFamilyVM, "Family Code/Name:")
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
                <!-- <input asp-for="PublisherFamilyVM.PubDataList.FamilyCode" class="form-control" /> -->

                <input id="input_family_code" class="form-control" type="text" value="" onblur="getfamilyname();" />
            </div>

            <div class="col-4">
            <!-- <input asp-for="PublisherFamilyVM.FamilyList.FamilyName" class="form-control" /> -->

            <input id="input_family_name" class="form-control" type="text" value="" />
            </div>
            <span asp-validation-for="PublisherFamilyVM.PubDataList.FamilyCode" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-6 offset-2">
                <partial name="_CreateAndBackToListButton" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>


@section Scripts{
    @{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial"); }

<script>
    function getfamilyname() {
        var familycode = $("#input_family_code").val();

        if (familycode != "") {
            $.getJSON(`/eventinfo?handler=FamilyNameByCode&familycode=${familycode}`, function (data) {
                //console.log(data);
                $("#input_family_name").empty();
                $("#input_family_name").val(data);
            });
        }
</script>

}

    ***** PageModel *****
    
            public JsonResult OnGetFamilyNameByCode(string familycode)
    
            {
                //code logic here
                //retrieve data from database based on famiycode
                return new JsonResult(familycode);
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

> When the EventCode is entered and the user exits the field, I want to trigger an event that queries the EvCode table using the the value in the EventCode field to select the EventType, then populate the the EventType field with the value.

To achieve above requirement, you can try to make AJAX request to handler method then dynamically populate value of EventType input field based on returned value in `blur` event of EventCode input field, like below.

```
<input id="input_event_code" type="text" value="" onblur="geteventtype();" />
<input id="input_event_type" type="text" value=""/>
```

JS code

```
function geteventtype() {
    var eventcode = $("#input_event_code").val();

    if (eventcode!="") {
        $.getJSON(`/eventinfo?handler=EventTypeByCode&eventcode=${eventcode}`, function (data) {
            //console.log(data);
            $("#input_event_type").empty();
            $("#input_event_type").val(data);
        });
    }

    //...
}
```

handler method

```
public JsonResult OnGetEventTypeByCode(int eventcode)
{
    //code logic here
    //retrieve data from database based on eventcode
    //...
    return new JsonResult(eventtype);
}
```

Test Result

[image]

***Update:***

> A 404 error does on the $.getJSON line of code indicating the url cannot be found. I replaced '/eventinfo?handler= FamilyNameByCode&familycode=${familycode}' - with - '/Create?handler = FamilyNameByCode&familycode=${familycode}' Do a need to add the folder or something else?

Please check if your `Create` model class look like below.

```
public class CreateModel : PageModel
{
    //properties here
    //...

    public void OnGet()
    {

    }

    public JsonResult OnGetFamilyNameByCode(int familycode)
    {
        //code logic here
        //retrieve data from database based on eventcode
        //...
        return new JsonResult("FamilyName_Here");
    }
}
```

Comment: Fei Han - Thank you for your suggestions and code. I used a different project where I trying to accomplish the same thing. The only differences, rather than using EventCode I used FamilyCode, and rather than use EventType I used FamilyName. The handler (OnGetFamilyNameByCode) was never called.

I've included my code with the original post, maybe you can see what I've done wrong.`

Comment: `The handler (OnGetFamilyNameByCode) was never called.` You can capture that Ajax request you made and check if there is 404 error in browser F12 developer tool Network tab.

Comment: A 404 error does on the $.getJSON line of code indicating the url cannot be found.  I replaced '/eventinfo?handler= FamilyNameByCode&familycode=${familycode}' - with - '/Create?handler = FamilyNameByCode&familycode=${familycode}'    Do a need to add the folder or something else?

Comment: Hi @ATA, please make sure you make request with correct URL, and please check if your `CreateModel` class is same/similar as my update code.